# finding products that are bought together Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relation

I am using Laravel and eloquent If I have the following two tables

```
Sales
----
|id|
|--|
|1 |
|2 |
|3 |
|4 |
----

Sales_data
----
|sale_id|Product_id|
|------------|
|   1    | 30 |
|   1    | 24 |
|   1    | 18 |
|   2    | 18 |
|   2    | 30 |
|   3    | 24 |
|   4    | 18 |
|   4    | 24 |
--------------
```

I would like to retrieve the following info:

```
| Product_id   | bought_with | times_bought_together |
|--------------|-------------|-----------------------|
|       30     |     18      |            2          |
|       30     |     24      |            1          |
|       24     |     18      |            1          |
------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the relation in Sales model, to the sale_data

```
    public function data()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\SaleData::class, 'sale_id');
    }
```

Thank you verry much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DB::select() so you can put RAW SQL statements in it.
In this case its easyer to just use RAW SQL

```
DB::select("SELECT c.product_id, c.bought_with, count(*) as times_bought_together
FROM (
  SELECT a.product_id as product_id, b.product_id as bought_with
  FROM sales_data a
  INNER join sales_data b
  ON a.sale_id = b.sale_id AND a.product_id != b.product_id) c
GROUP BY c.product_id, c.bought_with
ORDER BY times_bought_together DESC LIMIT 50")
```

GoodLuck if you have the same problem!